# Copy range from Excel to PPT in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I am trying to copy and paste a range in excel to ppt as a table by using the Powerpoint macro below.  For some reason it won't allow me to paste in ppt the way I have the code written and I am very confused why. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

```
Public Sub RangeToPresentation(ByVal sheetName As String, NamedRange As Excel.Range)
    Dim ppApp As Object
    Dim ppPres As Object
    Dim PPSlide As Object

    Set ppApp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")

    Set ppPres = ppApp.ActivePresentation
    ppApp.ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewNormal

    ' Select the last (blank slide)
    Dim longSlideCount As Integer
    longSlideCount = ppPres.Slides.Count
    ppPres.Slides(1).Select

    Set PPSlide = ppPres.Slides(ppApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex)


    NamedRange.Copy

    ' Paste the range
    PPSlide.Paste.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Does it error anywhere?

Comment: Yes at `PPSlide.Paste.Select`

Comment: Object doesnt support this property or method

Comment: Well considering I know this code from the other questions you have posted with similar needs, you seem to be copying an Excel range as is (just using `.Copy` instead of the Copy as Picture) and I don't think Pasting that directly into PPT is supported.

Comment: It pastes perfectly file into PPT if I do it myself though...

Comment: I do not want to paste the picture though. I want to paste the table.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this:

```
 ppApp.ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewNormal

' Select the last (blank slide)
Dim longSlideCount As Integer
longSlideCount = ppPres.Slides.Count
ppPres.Slides(1).Select

Set PPSlide = ppPres.Slides(ppApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex)


NamedRange.Copy

' Paste the range
PPSlide.Paste.Select
```

With this:

```
 ppApp.ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewNormal

' No need to select the slide
' And slide indexes are longs, not integers
Dim longSlideCount As Long
longSlideCount = ppPres.Slides.Count

NamedRange.Copy

' Paste the range; don't select it.
ppPres.Slides(ppPres.Slides.Count).Shapes.Paste
```

This is off top of head, but give it a try, let us know how it works out